# dynamicIpSecurity is not Working on Azure Web App

Tags: dynamic, azure-web-app-service, ip-restrictions

I have used the code on web.config to enforce Dynamic IP Restrictions to deny concurrent requests like 10 within 10 seconds and concurrent request at same time like 5 requests.

```
<security>
  <dynamicIpSecurity denyAction="Unauthorized">
  <denyByRequestRate enabled="true" maxRequest="10" RequestIntervalInMillisecond="10000"/>
  <denyByConcurrentRequests enabled="true" maxConcurrentRequests="5"/>
  </dynamicIpSecurity>
</security>
```

The application is .net 4.7 framework and it is an MVC application.
When I publish the same on Azure Web App, it does not work.

When I try to send a request like 35 on Fiddler with same Azure URL, all the requests are been responded with 200 OK status.

I have tried the web.config code

```
<security>
  <dynamicIpSecurity denyAction="Unauthorized">
    <denyByRequestRate enabled="true" maxRequest="10" RequestIntervalInMillisecond="10000"/>
    <denyByConcurrentRequests enabled="true" maxConcurrentRequests="5"/>
  </dynamicIpSecurity>
</security>

<security>
  <dynamicIpSecurity denyAction="Unauthorized">
    <denyByRequestRate enabled="true" maxRequest="10" RequestIntervalInMillisecond="10000"/>
    <denyByConcurrentRequests enabled="true" maxConcurrentRequests="5"/>
  </dynamicIpSecurity>
</security>
```

Comment: Code:<security>
       <dynamicIpSecurity denyAction="Unauthorized">
         <denyByRequestRate enabled="true" maxRequest="10" RequestIntervalInMillisecond="10000"/>
         <denyByConcurrentRequests enabled="true" maxConcurrentRequests="5"/>
       </dynamicIpSecurity>
    </security>

Comment: I have repaired the code blocks in your post. Consider deleting the comment again if the code looks ok in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try below tag and see if it works. try requestedIntervalInMilliseconds instead of RequestIntervalInMillisecond.

```
<security>
  <dynamicIpSecurity denyAction="Unauthorized">
    <denyByRequestRate enabled="true" maxRequest="10" requestedIntervalInMilliseconds="10000"/>
    <denyByConcurrentRequests enabled="true" maxConcurrentRequests="5"/>
  </dynamicIpSecurity>
</security>
```